# Toast.makeText activity context error?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to Android, Eclipse and partly Java (decade ago I read a Java book and never used it.) I am following this tutorial: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449390501/Android_User_Interface.html

I have this code:

```
public class Status extends Activity implements OnClickListener, TextWatcher {
  // ...
  class PostToTwitter extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    // ...
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
      Toast.makeText(Status.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

I get these errors next to the **Toast.makeText** line:

> - The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (AsyncTask.Status, String, int)
> - No enclosing instance of the type AsyncTask.Status is accessible in scope

1. I am not sure why I get an error?
2. Why is it mentioning AsyncTask when I am passing the Status activity context?

I guess I am going to slap myself and say Doh! later, but I have starred myself blind at it now :)

Comment: are you getting any error in logcat if so can u put that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that [`Status`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html) is a public [enum of AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#nestedclasses). So java takes not your activity as a context. Try to hold a instance of your context in your `AsyncTask`.

Try this code here:

```
public class Status extends Activity implements OnClickListener, TextWatcher {
  private Context context;
  public void onCreate(...) {
    context=this;
    //...
  }

  // ...
  class PostToTwitter extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    // ...
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Did not hink of it myself, but it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Toast.makeText(com.package.name.Status.this, "Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Replace `com.package.name` to package name of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the context to the AsyncTask, including it in the "PostToTwitter" constructor. For example, when you instantiate the class, pass getApplicationContext() (or "this", if calling from an Activity). Then, use that context in the Toast, instead of Status.this:

```
      Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Toast get the error in onPostExecute() method use ProgressDialoge or debugging by

> Log.d("result",result+"");

Answer (score 0):

whether your asyntask is inner class in Status Activity and if then use public keyword with as

```
public class PostToTwitter extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
// ...
    public void onPostExecute(String result) { 
    Toast.makeText(Status.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }
```

No problem with Status.this and if your Asyntask is not an inner class then you need to pass it in Constructor as